# Is charge quantization correctly interpreted in classical electrodynamics?

Tags: electrostatics, approximations, discrete, protons

As I tried to answer the SE question [**Electric fields in continuous charge distribution**](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/509624/electric-fields-in-continuous-charge-distribution), I faced many ambiguities regarding this matter. In classical electrodynamics, it is claimed that the electric field near a vast plate is constant (uniform) considering that the charges are continuously distributed (uniformly) all over an infinite plane. The electric field is thus calculated to be:

$$E=\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_0} \space ,$$

where $\sigma$ is the surface charge density. However,  in reality, the charge is quantized, and the electric field very close to the radius of these particles (a proton for instance) is near to the order of $E\approx 10^{22} \space V/m$ which is extremely high. When I considered $\frac{L}{d}×\frac{L}{d}=\frac{L^2}{d^2}$ number of these particles building an $L×L$ mesh of charges, so that the distance between every two successive charges is $d$ along both $x$ and $y$ axes, I deduced:

$$E=\frac{e}{\pi\epsilon_0} \sum_{n=0}^{\frac{L/2}{d}}\sum_{m=0}^{\frac{L/2}{d}}\space \frac{z}{(n^2d^2+m^2d^2+z^2)^{3/2}} \space$$

where $e$ is the charge of each particle (proton). Moreover, I assumed $L\gg d \gg z$. The above equation shows the field of the mesh, a distance $z$ exactly above the charge located at the center of the plate. However, when $z$ approaches zero, I numerically calculated that $E$ tends to infinity. This obviously violates the classical result of $E=\sigma/(2\epsilon_0)$, which indicates a constant field for a large uniformly charged plane. Does my calculation show that the electric field very close to, say, a plate capacitor is no longer constant but rather extremely great?

If this deduction is correct, the field component of a single particle (proton) parallel to the plate can also get high values very close to each proton, whereas we know that the E-field is zero inside the plate, otherwise we would have current. Where is the problem?

Comment: shouldn't you exclude $(n,m)=(0,0)$?

Comment: I do not think so! Because it designates the field of the central charge itself at $z$.

Answer (score 1):

Your deduction is correct.  The *average* field, which only makes sense at distances substantially farther than the spacing between point charges, is constant.  But very close to any given point charge, the effective field is dominated by the inverse-square field of the point charge.  Classical electromagnetic theory stipulates continuous charge & current densities, but in fact at the scale of individual particles there is no such thing.

Comment: However, the correctness of this deduction contradicts this well-known sentence which can be found in any textbook: *The electric field is zero **everywhere** inside the conductor*

Comment: @MohammadJavanshiry In electrostatics, as in everywhere in physics, context is essential. Basically all of classical electrostatics is done in a continuum approximations, where only average fields and charge densities are meaningful, and the details of the microscopic fields are neglected. (Moreover, if you wanted to describe those microscopic details, then you'd need to be doing it within a quantum mechanical framework, anyways.)

Comment: If it's a conductor where electrons can move freely, they will tend to move where the forces push them. When there is a lack of electrons, electrons on the surface will tend to move inward so that the positive charges are concentrated on the surface, more or less equally spaced apart. Similarly when there's a surplus of electrons, they get pushed to the surface where they get spaced more or less equally apart. It isn't 100% but close enough for an approximation.

Comment: Classical ectrodynamics also acknowleges the lack of perfection in the continuum approximation in the treatment of continuous media by adding polarization terms to deduce medium properties like index of refraction from an atomic model. This is still only a first order correction, but it covers the vast majority of practical cases. Many of the remaining cases of addressed in the classical treatment of non-linear optics. In other words classical physics handles hard cases in purterbation series. But we knew that.

Answer (score 0):

Classical physicists found that their predictions were largely correct on a macro scale. Approximating charge as continuous across charged conductive surfaces worked adequately.

They found reason to believe that charge is quantized. But it was hard to get accurate measures of what happens to single charges at tiny distances. Any attempt at measurement had to assume that macroscopic physical laws were the same, and that various physical constants were in fact constant.

They had to assume for example that the inverse square law applies the same at small distances -- that the real law is not something else which approximates inverse square at large distances.

For one example out of many, the formula

$0.5 (1 - \frac{D}{\sqrt{D^2+e_1}})$ approximates $\frac{1}{D^2}$ for large distance D, but approaches 0.5 when D approaches zero.

Coming at it from another direction, classical physicists were obligated to think of protons as homogeneous spheres by Occam's razor. Lacking reason to think otherwise, they had to assume the simplest case was true. So they could be treated as point particles. But we now think that protons are compound particles composed of quarks that have different charges. Three quarks don't have to form a sphere. And they could orient themselves in response to the charge of another proton. If they did that, then -- assuming inverse square -- we could get something like this:

++++....-..........++++....-

When they get close, the closest quarks have by far the biggest force.

++++....-.++++....-

(Sorry about the dots, I didn't quickly see how to keep spaces from being deleted.)

Classical physics was built on a tenuous web of assumptions that fit large-scale experimental evidence but that did not properly extrapolate down to tiny scales. That's just how it went.